# Why Sun's Arrays.sort implementation creates a clone of the input array?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, sun

Can someone please explain the following code?

Source: Arrays.class,

```
public static <T> void sort(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c) {
T[] aux = (T[])a.clone();
    if (c==null)
        mergeSort(aux, a, 0, a.length, 0);
    else
        mergeSort(aux, a, 0, a.length, 0, c);
}
```

1. Why create aux?
2. How is the sort ever working if the code sorts aux?
3. Isn't this a waste of resources to clone the array before sorting?

Comment: Why are you asking these questions?  You clearly have the source code in front of you, and the answers are obvious from just reading the javadoc comments for the `mergeSort` method.

Comment: @Stephen C: Your absolutely right. That's what happens when you post questions to SO at 3 in the morning (IST) instead of going to sleep. Anyway's good answers, I've learned from them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1: Why create aux?

Because the `mergeSort` method requires a source and destination array.

> 2: How is the sort ever working if the code sorts aux?

Because the `mergeSort` method sorts *from* `aux` *to* `a`

> 3: Isn't this a waste of resources to clone the array before sorting?

No it is not ... using that implementation of `mergeSort`.  Now if the `sort` returned a sorted array, doing a clone (rather than creating an empty array) would be wasteful.  But the API requires it to do an in-place sort, and this means that `a` must be the "destination".  So the elements need to copied to a temporary array which will be the "source".

If you take a look at the `mergeSort` method, you will see that it recursively partitions the array to be sorted, merging backwards and forwards between its source and destination arrays.  For this to work, you *need* two arrays.  Presumably, Sun / Oracle have determined that this algorithm gives good performance for typical Java sorting use-cases.

Answer (score 2):

Read the [`mergeSort` source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Arrays.java#Arrays.mergeSort%28java.lang.Object%5b%5d%2Cjava.lang.Object%5b%5d%2Cint%2Cint%2Cint%29).

It's a non-inplace sort with two parameters (`src` and `dest`).
It sorts the `dest` parameter and uses the `src` parameter for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Scroll down in that source file and look at how the recursive mergeSort works.  I think it's a bit too involved to try to explain in a post on here so here's a good reference:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort